# COMO EXECUTAR FUNÇÃO A CADA PERÍODO DE TEMPO - UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

Preciso executar essa função - que cria uma plataforma randomizada em posição randomizada - a cada 3 segundos .Como faz??

```
void CreatePlatform()
{
      System.Random random = new System.Random();
      int vectorNumber = random.Next(0, 5);

      Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-6.0f, 6f), 0);

      Instantiate(plataforms[VectorNumber], position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(6,6,0)));        
    }
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função `InvokeRepeating(string methodName, float time, float repeatRate);`

O primeiro parâmetro é o método que você quer chamar.

O segundo parâmetro é o tempo de espera antes de chamar a função pela primeira vez.

O terceiro parâmetro é o intervalo de tempo para chamar a função repetidamente.

No seu caso ficaria parecido com isso:

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("CreatePlatform", .01f, 3f);
    }

    void CreatePlatform()
    {
        System.Random random = new System.Random();
        int vectorNumber = random.Next(0, 5);

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-6.0f, 6f), 0);

        Instantiate(plataforms[VectorNumber], position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(6,6,0)));        
    } 
}
```

Para mais detalhes, consulte a documentação da Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html?_ga=2.239218051.1201192954.1593687853-1815494055.1593687853

Comment: Obrigadoo!!!!!!

Comment: Por nada, disponha :)